# FTP Connection in the HAproxy

Tags: haproxy

I use HAproxy for the first time. This is my HAproxy conf. file and everything works right without FTP connection.

Also, Installed pure-ftp on other guest servers, do I have to make a change in guest machines?

I can not access the servers via FTP.

```
 global
log 127.0.0.1   local0
 log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
#log loghost    local0 info
maxconn 4096
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon
#debug
#quiet
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

 defaults
log     global
mode    http
option  httplog
option  dontlognull
retries 3
redispatch
maxconn 2000
contimeout      5000
clitimeout      50000
srvtimeout      50000

listen stats
bind *:8080
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    option httpclose
    stats enable
    stats show-legends
    stats refresh 5s
    stats uri /stats
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth hello:world
    stats admin if TRUE

frontend MAIN 
bind *:21 
bind *:80 
bind *:143 
bind *:443 
bind *:993 
mode http 

    acl server1_URL hdr_dom(host) -i domain1.com
    acl server2_URL hdr_dom(host) -i domain2.com

use_backend server1 if server1_URL
use_backend server2 if server2_URL  

backend server1
mode http
server web-first 192.168.1.2:80

backend server2
mode http
server web-first 192.168.1.3:80
```

I tried this: *it did not work*

```
listen FTP :21,:10000-10250
mode tcp
server ftp01 192.168.1.2 check port 21
server ftp01 192.168.1.3 check port 21
```

What should I do for it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the ForcePassiveIP setting in the pure-ftpd configuration file. It should be set to the ip of the frontend proxy. Also, make sure the PassivePortRange setting matches what you have in your HAproxy configuration.

The FTP protocol is not straightforward to proxy as it makes multiple connections, though doing it at the tcp layer ought to be okay.